# Удаление указателя с помощью delete[] C++

Tags: c++

Добрый день. Хотелось бы узнать, в чем проблема.
Есть простой (ужасный) код для примера

```
class STRING_REPLACE
{
private:
    char* stringObj;
    int length=0;
public:
    STRING_REPLACE()
    {
        cout << "Creating STRING_REPLACE object\n";
        char* stringObj = new char[5];
        strcpy(stringObj, "FFFF\0");
        length = 5;
        cout << stringObj << endl;
    }
    int getLength()
    {
        return this->length;
    }
    void setString(std::string obj,int length)
    {

        delete[] stringObj;

        //stringObj = new char[length+1];
        //strcpy(this->stringObj, obj.c_str());
    }
    void getString()
    {
        cout << stringObj << endl;
    }

};

};
```

Почему в данном примере программа вылетает при вызове функций setString,getString?

Прошу не кидаться камнями за такой код. Такая реализация сделана умышленно.

Comment: "В данном примере" программа никак не может вылетать, ибо никакой программы тут нет. В программе на С++ должна присутствовать функция `main`. Где она у вас? Зачем в конце болтается лишняя `};`? Зачем в строковый литерал `"FFFF\0"` явно вписан символ `\0`?

Comment: Также не ясно в чем роль поля `length`. Что именно в нем хранится?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Потому что в конструкторе вы изволите выделять память, и полученный указатель совать в локальную переменную.

```
char* stringObj = new char[5];
```

А надо:

```
stringObj = new char[5];
```